# Displaying Column Names on the output (Android List View)

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have this picture of MySQL database:

[image]

And This is My php codes for fetching the data's from MySQL into Android through JSON :

```
<?php 

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($con,"qstatslite")or die("error");

$q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM queue_stats ORDER BY queue_stats_id DESC LIMIT 20");


$return_arr = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
//$return_arr['queue_stats_id'] = $row['queue_stats_id'];
$row_array['datetime'] = $row['datetime'];
$row_array['qname'] = $row['qname'];
$row_array['qagent'] = $row['qagent'];
$row_array['qevent'] = $row['qevent'];
$row_array['info1'] = $row['info1'];
$row_array['info2'] = $row['info2'];
$row_array['info3'] = $row['info3'];

 //$return_arr['queue'][] = array('name' = $tableName, 'queue' = $rows);


    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

$output = json_encode(array('queue' => $return_arr));
echo $output;

?>
```

And This is My Java Codes for the Android :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;


public class MainActivity2 extends ListActivity{

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private static String IPaddress = "http://192.168.1.102/";

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = IPaddress + "Projects/GetUsers.php";


    private static final String TAG_QUEUE = "queue"; 
    private static final String TAG_DATETIME = "datetime";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "qname"; 
    private static final String TAG_AGENT = "qagent"; 
    private static final String TAG_EVENT = "qevent";
    private static final String TAG_INFO1 = "info1";
    private static final String TAG_INFO2 = "info2";
    private static final String TAG_INFO3 = "info3";


    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray queue = null;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>queueList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        queueList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        ListView lv = getListView();



        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetEventCounter().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     * */
    private class GetEventCounter extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity2.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);


                    queue = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_QUEUE);


                    for (int i = 0; i < queue.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = queue.getJSONObject(i);           

                        String datetime = c.getString(TAG_DATETIME);
                        String qname = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String qagent = c.getString(TAG_AGENT);
                        String qevent = c.getString(TAG_EVENT);
                        String info1 = c.getString(TAG_INFO1);
                        String info2 = c.getString(TAG_INFO2);
                        String info3 = c.getString(TAG_INFO3);





                        HashMap<String, String> event = new HashMap<String, String>();


                        event.put(TAG_DATETIME, datetime);
                        event.put(TAG_NAME, qname);
                        event.put(TAG_AGENT, qagent);
                        event.put(TAG_EVENT, qevent);
                        event.put(TAG_INFO1, info1);
                        event.put(TAG_INFO2, info2);
                        event.put(TAG_INFO3, info3);



                        queueList.add(event);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity2.this, queueList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_DATETIME, TAG_NAME, TAG_AGENT, TAG_EVENT, TAG_INFO1, TAG_INFO2, TAG_INFO3}, 
                    new int[] { R.id.datetime, R.id.qname, R.id.qagent, R.id.qevent, R.id.info1, R.id.info2, R.id.info3 });

            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

}
```

And the Output on the android would be this :

[image]

Now, What I want for the Output is to Display The names of Columns from MySQL beside the output except for the Date and Time..

Just like this :

```
2016-06-16 17:32:32

qname : 5

qagent : 50

qevent : 7

info1 : 2

info2 : 91

info3 : 1
```

Can Someone teach me how to do that please? Sorry I'm a beginner in Android. Thanks a Lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about simplely change the block assign the entry?

```
String datetime = c.getString(TAG_DATETIME);

String datetime = String.format("%s : %s", TAG_DATETIME, c.getString(TAG_DATETIME));
```

and that part in your code you can refactor with a loop instead of many local String xxx variables.

Or you can go to check the SimpleAdapter's bindView implement, do your custom bind function by `setViewBinder()` or extends SimpleAdapter.

Or you can abandon the SimpleAdapter, use more flexible Adapter classes.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a Lot Son of Goku! :-D

Answer (score 0):

Use BaseAdapter instead SimpleAdapter . -_-#